# Fontspec creates left margin

Tags: margins, fontspec

I'm using `standalone` document class and trying to draw a TikZ picture. The picture have border which is the border of the page. I do it [like this](http://papeeria.com/p/c6949888bcd012d5fcc4ca5bd8ba79a9#/without-fontspec.tex):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\W{220}
\def\H{250}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- (\W,0) -- (\W,\H) -- (0,\H) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And it looks like this (I've added red background just to make the difference visible, and I've done it using gimp, it's not a part of the question)

[image: the left border at very left]

But if I just add `\usepackage{fontspec}` to the preamble then some left margin appears and it looks [like this](http://papeeria.com/p/c6949888bcd012d5fcc4ca5bd8ba79a9#/with-fontspec.tex)

[image: the left border moves to the right]

So, where does it come from? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Please don't add links but code to your question. We do not like external links for security reasons. It's nice that you post images, but maybe you should make some effort in order to find a better example than a just two rectangles. Thank you.

Comment: I get no difference, as far as I can see.

Comment: @egreg I've added red background to the pictures

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: @egreg I'm using `XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=xelatex 2014.7.21)`

Comment: I see the effect with TexLive 2013, but not with 2014 and miktex. So you will probably have to update something (fontspec?).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `fontspec` is not involved, as I get the shift as soon as I compile the example as is (no `fontspec`) with `xelatex` (TL 2013). However the effect seems to disappear at bigger magnification.

Comment: @egreg thank you. Looks like the simplest way is to update TL.

Comment: @GrigoryKalabin Did you try magnifying the PDF view in your PDF viewer?

Comment: @egreg yes, I did. The gap was there.

Comment: @egreg: On my system fontspec is involved. And the effect disappears if I add `\unskip` after `\begin{document}`. So it looks like an spurious space somewhere.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\unskip` solves the problem, thanks! Could you please create an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see the effect with TexLive 2013, but not with 2014 and miktex. So you will probably have to update something (fontspec?). The effect disappears if I add `\unskip` after `\begin{document}`. So it looks like an spurious space somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

[Ulrike has shown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200655) that this is a `fontspec` issue. The actually faulty code is

```
\tl_put_right:Nn \document
 {
  \tl_set_eq:NN \cyrillicencoding \g_fontspec_encoding_tl
  \tl_set_eq:NN \latinencoding    \g_fontspec_encoding_tl
 }
```

which is used to do something 'really late', just before the start of the document. The problem is that this gets added after the `\ignorespaces` that is at the end of the standard `\document` macro. This causes issues as there is a space (line end) after `\begin{document}`. Newer versions of `fontspec` avoid this by using the standard `\AtBeginDocument` hook, so the issue goes away. In cases where you *really* need to hook right at the end of `\document`, you have to always add an `\ignorespaces` as well as what you need, or use a 'patch' approach to essentially do the same thing.